# can we register setOnClickPendingIntent in onEnable() method of AppWidgetProvider class in android?

Tags: android, widget, broadcastreceiver

Can we register **setOnClickPendingIntent** in **onEnable()** method of **AppWidgetProvider** class in android?

I want this because **onEnable()** is called just one time if I register **setOnClickPendingIntent()** in `onUpdate()` method of **AppWidgetProvder**. It will repeatedly register itself again and again. How do I avoid this repetition?

Answer (score 0):

> can we register setOnClickPendingIntent in onEnable() method of AppWidgetProvider class in android?

No. You do not have a `RemoteViews` there.

> if i register setOnClickPendingIntent() in onUpdate() method of AppWidgetProvder it will repeatedly register it self again and again

Correct. This is perfectly normal. In `onUpdate()`, you need to create and define a `RemoteViews` that is your app widget UI. This includes registering for click events.

In terms of the "again and again" part, `onUpdate()` will not be called very often, unless you are doing something very bad in your implementation.

> how to avoid this repeation.

Stop writing an app widget, I guess.